# Azure Service Fabric – Service Remoting vs HTTP vs messaging system?

Tags: azure, microservices, messaging, azure-service-fabric, stateful-actor-service

Let say I’ll have millions of Actors producing data that will end up in a DB. It would be a terrible idea to let the Actors interact with the DB so I’m adding another Service B in the middle. This Service B will write to DB in batches.

What should I use for the communication between Actors and Service B? Service Remoting, HTTP, an asynchronous messaging system?

Is Service Remoting a good solution? Especially when data is already persisted in the Actor (StatePersistence.Persisted)

Can Service Remoting handle millions of Actors concurrently calling Service B? Can you mention anything negative about going with the Service Remoting approach?

Thanks

Comment: Found this article to choose communication mechanism on service fabric. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/10/28/my-experiment-and-observation-on-service-fabric-communication-stacks/ Please check.

Comment: Thanks @JJa it was helpful